# Change Rails namespaced route to personalized params route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

TL;DR: I want to have `username621/posts/title-of-post` instead of `member/posts/1`

The changing of post `id` to post `title` was easy enough since I used the `freindly_id` gem to generate the slugs.

However, I am having difficulty routing to a personalized params route instead of the current namespaced route. Here is the current routing:

```
namespace :member do
    resources :posts
end
```

I want to replace the `member` namespace to user's `username`. So if their username is `user123`, the route should be `user123/posts/title-of-post`.

I think that this is not very standard Rails routing and tried looking for similar questions with no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for more complicated `routes.rb`, add a `path` option

```
namespace :member, path: ":user_id" do
  resources :posts
end
```

should get what you want, e.g. http://localhost:3000/621/posts/1

then we just have to add [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) to `User` and `Post` to have it become something like `http://localhost:3000/username621/posts/title-of-post`

however, you'll need to pore through the codebase for things like `member_post_path(post)` and change to `member_post_path(post.user, post)`

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `namespace` and adding `path` option:

```
resources :posts, path: '/:username/posts/'
```

Then if you access `/username621/posts/title-of-post` in your controller you'll see `params[:username] = 'username621'`

If you have other paths of the form `/something/posts` add them above this route, otherwise they will be caught by `:username`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying out your solution since the actual routes are much more complicated than the posted answer and will take some time. Will confirm if this works in a while.